# Flutter app apk installation fails on Android 7.1.2 device

Tags: android, flutter

I developed a simple Flutter (2.5.3) app which runs a webview. I managed to install the app locally on my smartphone (Android 11) via a .apk file. But when I try to install the same apk file on an older industry PC which runs Android 7.1.2, I keep getting this error at the beginning of the installation: "App not installed. This app isn't compatible with your tablet."

I tried:

- I adjusted Android security settings to allow installation of apps from an unknown source
- I adjusted the minimum API level (19) as well as target API (25) level to match Android 7.1.2

What else could I have missed?

Comment: Just confirming that you can install/run a simple Java/Kotlin "Hello World with WebView APK" on the industrial device.

Comment: No, I managed to install the app on a different device (smartphone with Android 11) but not on the industrial device running Android 7.1.2.

Comment: Its possible that the industrial device requires special signing keys to install regardless of 'unknown source' setting. If a Java/Kotlin 'Hello World' doesn't install/run you may need to reach out to the manufacturer.

Comment: I will check back on that. Currently, the app is not signed at all but that did not seem to be problem on my smartphone...

Comment: The problem was indeed the missing signing of the app. Even though I activated the "allow apps from unknown sources" option, that specific Android device would not allow to install unsigned apps. Once I signed the app, I was able to install it.